# Report Builder 3 - Hiding multiple text boxes

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

Have 3 text boxes and only one can be visible based on the field dept i.e AAA,BBB and CCC.

Three text boxes txtBodyText_1, txtBodyText_2 , txtBodyText_3

If Field data returns AAA then visible txtBodyText_1 and the others hidden.

If Field data returns BBB then visible txtBodyText_2 and the others hidden

If Field data returns CCC then visible txtBodyText_3 and the others hidden

have used on the visibility hidden text box properties :

txtBodyText_1:

`=iif(Dept.value, "EmpDetails")="AAA",true,false)`

txtBodyText_2:

`=iif(Dept.value, "EmpDetails")="BBB",true,false)`

txtBodyText_3:

`=iif(Dept.value, "EmpDetails")="CCC",true,false)`

Any ideas for a better solution...

Comment: Note that if the expression is evaluated to True the textbox is hidden but you want it to be visible. You will have to switch the True and False values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you switch your "=" to "<>" they should work as you intend.

```
=iif(Dept.value, "EmpDetails")<>"AAA",true,false)
```

Note that in the dialogs the property is named Visibility, but in the property window it is named Hidden.  True = Hidden, False = Visible.

This equates to if Dept.value <> "AAA", Hide txtBodyText_1, else Show txtBodyText_1.